# How to resolve gem dependencies when installing rbenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rbenv

Recently I have installed rbenv and specified ruby to 2.3.1 and rails to 5.1.1 but I couldn't run my projects because I got:

```
Ignoring json-2.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 2.1.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.4
Ignoring yajl-ruby-1.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine yajl-ruby --version 1.3.1
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize': Could not find unf_ext-0.0.7.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
...
from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<main>'
```

**I ran:**

```
bundle install
```

**Installation passed successfully, but... Now I get:**

```
/home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/lib/ffi_c.so (LoadError)
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.8/lib/rb-inotify/native.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.8/lib/rb-inotify/native.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.8/lib/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.8/lib/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alex/pnv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib
    ...
    from /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

And I have no idea how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated!

***UPDATE 1***:
Finally, I've found source of the evil bug - nevertheless, I specify Rails 5.1.1, when I run rails new app_name, it installs 5.1.6! And seems like it uses 5.1.6 gem dependencies... Still don't know how to resolve instead of upgrading to >= 5.1.6

Comment: In that case in your Gemfile, add the line `gem rails, '5.1.1'`

Comment: @AkashPinnaka Thank you, that's it! I had to specify the version! Please, modify your answer so I could accept it!

Comment: Updated the answer @AlexanderGorg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your Gemfile.

`gem 'rails', '5.1.1'`

Run  `bundle install`

Comment: Can you try `bundle uninstall ffi` and `bundle install` again?

Comment: If you got 'could not find command uninstall', it seems you accidentally skipped `bundle`. Try `bundle uninstall ffi` instead of `uninstall ffi`. You could try that next time. But glad to hear your problem is solved :). @AlexanderGorg